# WooCommerce edit order privilledge

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Hello i made a new role using Ultimate Member named stock_user 
i want all users in the stock_user role only thing they can do 
  is to   change the order status in wooCommerce admin page from processing to shipped only

i tried plugins but nothing worked im sorry i don't have any code but i don't know  where to start

can anyone tell me where to start to make this work ?

[image] 
  i want to limit this dropdown menu options to processing & shipped only when a user with privildge stock_user is logged in

EDIT 2:  Its now working as it should thank to IndexTwo Answer but the problem is that inventory role is a custom role made by Ultimate Member plugin how can i make the status work with it ? here is the code of Indextwo

```
    function vnm_remove_woo_statuses($statuses) {
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

    $removeStatusesArray = array('pending', 'completed', 'cancelled', 'refunded', 'failed', 'refund-issued', 'shipping-progress', 'on-hold');

    //  If it's inventory user role

    if ( in_array('inventory', $currentUser->roles)) {

        foreach ($removeStatusesArray as $status) {
            if (isset($statuses['wc-' . $status])) {
                unset($statuses['wc-' . $status]);
            }
        }
    }

    return $statuses;
}

add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'vnm_remove_woo_statuses');
```

i mean it works when i change inventory to administrator just fine but how to get it working with the custom role (inventory) ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach the logic on this, but here's the function first:

```
function vnm_remove_woo_statuses($statuses) {
    $currentUser = wp_get_current_user();

    $removeStatusesArray = array('pending', 'completed', 'cancelled', 'refunded', 'failed', 'refund-issued', 'shipping-progress', 'on-hold');

    //  If it's any role other than administrator, remove the status

    if (!in_array('administrator', $currentUser->roles)) {

        foreach ($removeStatusesArray as $status) {
            if (isset($statuses['wc-' . $status])) {
                unset($statuses['wc-' . $status]);
            }
        }
    }

    //  ALWAYS need to return the status array regardless

    return $statuses;
}

add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'vnm_remove_woo_statuses', 5, 1);
```

Note the last line of the function: you **always** need to return the value of a filter, regardless of the logic therein - otherwise things go wonky. I've also set a high priority of `5` just in case anything else was hooking in.

The conditional logic is currently set to remove statuses if ANY role other than `administrator` tried to edit an order:

```
if (!in_array('administrator', $currentUser->roles)) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

In your example, you were removing the statuses *only* for administrators. You could switch that around so that it only happens for `stock_user` users:

```
if (in_array('stock_user', $currentUser->roles)) { /* Do stuff */ }
```

...however, be aware that if you have the ability to add multiple roles to a user and add `Stock User` to an administrator, their access to ordser statuses would also be restricted here.

Comment: @mohamedadel No problem - glad it worked for you 

Comment: hello sorry it was working but i got an error now
`ts parameter 1 to be array, null given in E:\xampp\htdocs\zumra\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-order-functions.php on line 323

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in E:\xampp\htdocs\zumra\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-order-functions.php on line 325`
  and the order status are empty when i open an account other than stock_user  
 using the code   `( in_array('stock_user', $currentUser->roles)`

Comment: @mohamedadel It's impossible to tell without seeing your code, but it sounds like your function isn't returning the status array. As noted in my answer, you **absolutely must** return the status array at the end of the function - _outside_ of your own conditional statement - otherwise it will fail.

Comment: Sorry i edited the post your code working just fine but there is one more problem i faced i would appreciate another help :)

Comment: i searched an i found that because im creating the role using a plugin i have to use 
`add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'function' );` but i can't get it to work in my code

Comment: i figured it out sorry it was um_inventory instead of inventory cuz im using um plugin all solved now thank you